# Expected Value of a Decision Based On Binary Machine Learning Model

Tags: self-study, expected-value, spark-mllib

I have developed a model to predict the failure of equipment in the field where, in the event of an unplanned failure, the cost of repair and loss of revenue is high.  On the other hand, if a malefaction is predicted there is a cost in deploying resources to prevent the potential failure.  But, more importantly there are limited resources that may be deployed in the event of multiple simultaneous alarms.  Some assets in the field produce greater revenue than others thus a choice must be made on what asset to address based on the probability of the failure event predicted by the model and the value of the given asset.

My question is: how does one calculate the expected value (cost) of a prediction given the model results (Spark Random forest), the raw probably and probability (confidence, as described in the Spark Random forest documentation) for each predicted event, and the confusion matrix of the training set?  This has to do with how to combine the probability of the event predicted by the model and the chance of false alarms and false negatives.

Comment: You should add the self-study tag.

Comment: @MichaelChernick this is not a self study question.  I know there is a proper way to calculate the expected value, I am just not sure how.  A definitive reference would be great!

Comment: Self-study does not mean that you know the answer.  It could be for homework but is a broader category.  If you use the tag some members might provide hints with comments.  Otherwise your question may not get any attention.

Comment: @MichaelChernick thanks for the tip.  I have added.  I am new to asking questions here.

Comment: Good.  I hope that you will get help.  Sorry that I have nothing to help you with at the moment.